# Regex check repeating characters

Tags: java, regex

I need to do a check for a 5-digit number using regex. Check condition: 1. There should be no more than 2 repeating digits (type 11234). 2. There should be no sequence 12345 or 54321.
I am trying to do this:
`var PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=[\\\\D]*\\\\d)(?!.*(\\\\d)\\\\1)(?!.*\\\\2{3,}){5,}.*$"`,
But checking for 12345 or 54321 doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1\d*\1)(?!12345)(?!54321)\d{5}$` https://regex101.com/r/Nh45dx/1

Comment: are `23456`, `09876`, or `12121` or `12131` acceptable?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code.  Good luck 

Comment: I mean regex excluding any forward or backward sequence of consecutive digits

Answer (score 4):

You can assert for not 3 of the same digits, and assert not 12345 and 54321.

Note to double escape the backslash in Java `\\d`.

```
^(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1\d*\1)(?!12345)(?!54321)\d{5}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1\d*\1)` Negative lookahead, do not match 3 times the same digits using 2 backreferences `\1`
- `(?!12345)` Assert not 12345
- `(?!54321)` Assert not 54322
- `\d{5}` Match 5 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nh45dx/1)

Or fail the match immediately, if the string does not consists of 5 digits, and match 1+ digits if all the assertions succeed.

```
^(?=\d{5}$)(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1\d*\1)(?!12345)(?!54321)\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jHrimJ/1)

If you don't want to match ascending and descending sequences for digits 0-9, you might either manually check the string for each hardcoded sequence, or generate the sequences and add them to a list.

Then you can check if the sequence of 5 digits is in the list, and remove the exact check with the lookarounds from the pattern.

```
List<String> sequences = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    StringBuilder sequence = new StringBuilder();
    int last = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        ++last;
        if (last > 9) last = 0;
        sequence.append(last);
    }
    sequences.add(sequence.toString());
    sequences.add(sequence.reverse().toString());
}

String[] strings = {"12345", "54321", "34567", "90123", "112341", "12356", "00132"};

for (String s : strings) {
    if ((!sequences.contains(s)) && s.matches("^(?=\\d{5}$)(?!\\d*(\\d)\\d*\\1\\d*\\1)\\d+$")) {
        System.out.printf("%s is not a sequence and does not contain 3 of the same digits\n", s);
    }
}
```

Output

```
12356 is not a sequence and does not contain 3 of the same digits
00132 is not a sequence and does not contain 3 of the same digits
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/xUJcIO)

Comment: You can eliminate cases like `23456` and `09876` using a little bit of java code `!"1234567890".contains(pass) && !"0987654321".contains(pass)`